# Unable to set audit rule for accept on Ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, system-calls, audit

I'm trying to audit accept syscalls on an old VM:

```
vagrant-ubuntu-precise-32# auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S accept
Syscall name unknown: accept
vagrant-ubuntu-precise-32#
```

Any ideas why this is happening?